# Getting data from $_POST within a for loop

Tags: php, html, css, post, http-post

If I have some hidden inputs in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="somedata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry0" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry1" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry2" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry3" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry4" value="moredata">
```

Now, once the form is submitted and I'm getting the data from the post, if I try and call `$_POST['test']` then I get my "somedata" value back. But if I do this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
{
  $x = 'entry{$i}';
  echo $_POST[$x]; // This does not work.
}
```

Then I do not get my "moredata" values back for each 'entry' input. If I print out the string defined as `$x`, then I get the string I'm after but it doesn't seem to want to work like this with `$_POST`. Anyone got any ideas how I can get around this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it a typo is copying?? `$POST` instead of  `$_POST`

Comment: @ing0, look at the solution proposed by garvey, this may be a better way of doing this.

Comment: I tried that method but it didn't work! The answered answer worked though!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside string literals, variables are only interpolated if the string literal is enclosed in double quotes:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
  $x = "entry{$i}";
  echo $_POST[$x];
}
```

For additional safety, you may want to check whether `array_key_exists($x, $_POST)` before subscripting `$_POST`, otherwise you would get an error of level `E_NOTICE` if the passed fields do not correspond.

Comment: Thanks. Was not aware about the double quotes! +1

Answer (score 3):

Try to use array notation:

```
<input type="hidden" name="entry[0]" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry[1]" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry[2]" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry[3]" value="moredata">
<input type="hidden" name="entry[4]" value="moredata">

<?php
echo implode($_POST['entry']);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    echo $_POST['entry'][$i];
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution! I second that.

Answer (score 0):

It is `$_POST` and not `$POST`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check:

echo $POST[$x]; // This does not work.

should be

echo $_POST[$x]; // Note the underscore.